# PHP Mail Reply-To: hotmail issue

Tags: php, email, hotmail

I have a contact form that generates an email. If the customer has an Hotmail account (that I put in the Reply-To part of the header) then the email is not sent, any other email address is fine and the email sends without a problem.

For example:

if $contactEmail is mail@hotmail.com the email is not sent.

if $contactEmail is mail@site.com the email is sent.

Here is my Header ...

```
$headers = "From: My Site <info@mysite.com>\r\n"; 
$headers .= "X-Sender: <info@mysite.com>\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: $contactEmail\r\n";  
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";  
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";  
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP4\r\n";   
$headers .= "X-Priority: 3\r\n";  
$headers .= "Return-Path: <info@mysite.com>\r\n";
```

Any thoughts/advice please?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the email in the Junk-Email folder?

Answer (score 0):

As per the PHP manual regarding [sending HTML mail](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#example-3357), try adding the "to" header:

```
$headers = "From: My Site <info@mysite.com>\r\n"; 
$headers .= "To: Whoever <whoever@othersite.com>\r\n"; 
$headers .= "X-Sender: <info@mysite.com>\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: $contactEmail\r\n";  
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";  
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";  
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP4\r\n";   
$headers .= "X-Priority: 3\r\n";  
$headers .= "Return-Path: <info@mysite.com>\r\n";
```

Comment: I tried adding the "to" header and it still doesn't send.  To answer the other suggestions.. the email doesn't end up in spam it simply doesn't get sent.

Answer (score 0):

Try jerdiggity's answer first and check if the mail ends in the junk folder. Microsoft's SmartScreen spam technology is very hard to come by. You have to create an DNS SPF record and “un-junk” some mails in order to get your IP whitelisted.